# Getting strange error code when programmatically adding a machine to a domain using C#

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to add a Windows machine (server 2008 R2) to a domain programmatically using C#. I know I have the correct permissions to add the machine to the domain because I am able to add it manually through the windows UI. I also know that my ManagementScope is correct because when I create it I am able to query any WMI object that I want. I am trying to connect as follows:

```
ManagementClass computerSystem = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("Win32_ComputerSystem"), new ObjectGetOptions());
ManagementObjectCollection computerSystemInstances = computerSystem.GetInstances();
ManagementObject baseObject = computerSystemInstances.ToList<ManagementObject>().First();

ManagementBaseObject inParams = baseObject.GetMethodParameters("JoinDomainOrWorkgroup");
inParams["Name"] = "my.domain.com";
inParams["Password"] = domainCredentials.FullUserName;
inParams["UserName"] = domainCredentials.Password;
inParams["FJoinOptions"] = 1;

var joinParams = baseObject.InvokeMethod("JoinDomainOrWorkgroup", inParams, null);
```

The method invoke does not throw any exceptions, but the error code value found at `joinParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value` is 1312. I can't find any documentation anywhere (even on Microsoft's MSDN page for the method) stating what this error code means. Does anyone know where to find what this error code is for?

Comment: Did the solutions below work for you?

Comment: Yes, I had the password/username swapped. Switching them fixed the issue I was seeing.

Comment: Cool, I thought it was something completely different haha nevermind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you've transposed your username and password to the wrong variables.  This may be the cause?

Comment: Ahhhhh - that was totally it. Thanks for the second pair of eyes!

Comment: My pleasure mate.  Nothing like a fresh perspective ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a system error code, found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681385%28v=vs.85%29

```
ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION
1312 (0x520)
A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
```